# Upload artifacts with the Windows Runner

Tags: windows, artifacts, gitlab-ci, runner

We use a official [Windows runner](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner) from Gitlab-ci. We want to upload artifacts.

We use the 'artifact' keyword in our yaml file to define the artefacts that need to be uploaded. When we commit this is the message we are getting:

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 0.7.2 (998cf5d)
WARNING: artifacts is not supported by selected executor and shell
Using Shell executor...
```

So is this because it is using a [Windows machine?](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/298) What is the deal here?

Comment: They are working on it apparently: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/merge_requests/52

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uploading artifacts from the windows shells `cmd` and `powershell` are currently not supported. After a while of digging the source I found that according to [gitlab-ci-multi-runner\shells\bash.go](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/shells/bash.go#L25) `bash` does support it.

The working solution for me is:

1. install Bash (already included with Git-SCM)
2. add the bash directory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`) to your `PATH`
3. make sure bash starts if you type `bash` in the `cmd`
4. find your config.toml and modify/add:

   ```
   executor = "shell"  
   shell = "bash"
   ```
5. restart your git-runner service
6. make sure your build scripts are in bash-syntax
   (for example run windows commands from bash with `cmd.exe /c "dir"`)

Comment: It's a answer on how to upload artefacts with the current version.

Comment: Beware that Gitlab documentation [advise](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/virtualbox.html#checklist-for-windows-vms) to use bash from Cygwin, not from Git for Windows.